# Finding limit of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence defined as

$${a_{n}}= \frac{1} {\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2} {3} + \frac{3} {\sqrt{28}} + \cdots \cdots + \frac{n} {\sqrt{n^3+1}}$$

and I want to find the limit of this sequence.

I think the limit is positive infinity, but I don't know what I should do in order to prove this.

Please give me some hints on how to approach this, thanks to anybody who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{n}},
$$
hence 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty.
$$

*Explanation, using series' methods*

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}}{\dfrac1n}=1
$$
and the series
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$
is divergent, hence also 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}
$$
id divergent, but $a_n$'s are partial sums of this series.

*More elementary explanation*

It is easy to see, that
$$
\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\geq\frac1n
$$
for all $n\geq2$. Let
$$
b_n=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n.
$$
It is certainly increasing, hence it remains to show, that it is unbounded. Let us consider 
$$
b_{2^n}=1+\frac12+\left(\frac13+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac15+\dots+\frac18\right)+\dots
+\left( \frac1{2^{n-1}+1}+\dots+\frac1{2^n}\right).
$$
But the value in every parentheses is greater than $\frac12$, hence $$
b^{2^n}>1+\frac{n}{2}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain this in a bit more detail？

Comment: @Lucy Certainly, but I don't know, which tools are allowed. Do you know something about series or it is an initial course of calculus?

Comment: This is for my analysis lesson, and I have learnt about sum rule, product rule, quotient rule, and ratio tests. I am also allowed to use some standard limit results.

Comment: @Lucy OK, hence the explanation by series, which I have put, is a bit to advanced. Please wait for an alternatibve version.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n > 1$

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3 +1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1/n^2 }}> \frac1{\sqrt{2n}}> \frac1{\sqrt{2}n},$$

and the series diverges because the harmonic series $\sum 1/n$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't learn about the comparison test yet, could you please explain using another method?

Comment: Do you know that $\sum 1/n$ diverges to infinity? You have $a_n > (1/\sqrt{2})\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k$.